# (non-Windows) platform lacking pthreads support

Tags: pthreads

Which operating system platform(s) (other than Windows) lack support for POSIX threads ("pthreads")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern, desktop or server oriented operating systems support POSIX threading.  There are even implementations for [Windows](http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32/) (although Windows doesn't support pthreads natively, and the open source implementations are typically a subset of pthread features).

The only non-Microsoft platforms I've seen that don't directly support pthreads are typically embedded systems.  Threading support on embedded OS platforms is often customized for that system's hardware, and doesn't use standard threading libraries.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you name some of these embedded systems please?

Comment: Palm OS, for example.  You could check individual ones listed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_operating_systems#Embedded
  Many don't support (at least complete) pthreads